# Build incremental std::string

Tags: c++

I try to build an `std::string` in the form of "start:Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;"
With following code I can build the repeated "Pdc" and the incremental string "123" but I'm unable to combine the two strings.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    std::string hdr("start:");
    std::fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ss), 3, "Pdc;");
    hdr.append(ss.str());

    std::string v("abc");
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), '1');

    std::cout << hdr << std::endl;
    std::cout << v << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Expected output: start:Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I build this string? Preferable without a `while` or `for` loop.
The expected output is: `start:Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string`s can be concatenated via their `operator+` (or `+=`) and integers can be converted via `std::to_string`:

```
std::string res("start:");

for (int i=0;i<3;++i){
    res += "Pdc" + std::to_string(i+1) + ";";
}
std::cout << res << "\n";
```

If you like you can use an algorithm instead of the handwritten loop, but it will still be a loop (your code has 2 loops, but only 1 is needed).

Answer (score 0):

Code to generate your expected string, though with a small for loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string cmd(const std::size_t N)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "start:";
    for(std::size_t n = 1; n <= N; ++n) os << "Pdc" << n << ";";
    return os.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << cmd(3ul);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, 3 is unknown at compile time.

Comment: Ok then it would become something with a small for loop though. (Example updated)